# Kubernetes rolling (gradual) scale out

Tags: kubernetes

We have a problem in which our pods, when they start, need to load some data, and the downstream service from which we are loading throttles these load requests. If we try to scale out by too many extra pods at once, the downstream service either becomes overwhelmed by the number of requests or just rejects them.

Is it possible to execute a gradual scale out to a deployment, similar to how rolling updates work?

Comment: I think it is possible to execute a gradual scale out to a deployment.  A [rolling update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/) allows a Deployment update to take place with zero downtime. It does this by incrementally replacing the current Pods with new ones. You can use ”Maxsurge” and “MaxUnavailable” settings during rolling updates in kubernetes, which helps in gradually scaling up ypur deployment. Refer to this [link](https://codefresh.io/learn/software-deployment/kubernetes-rolloing-deployment-a-practical-guide/) for more information.

Comment: I hope the above comment  was helpful to you in overcoming the issue. If it is, I will proceed to post that comment as a solution  to have greater visibility to community members. Looking forward to your feedback. I am happy to offer further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it is possible to execute a gradual scale out to a deployment. A rolling update allows a Deployment update to take place with zero downtime. It does this by incrementally replacing the current Pods with new ones. You can use ”**Maxsurge** '' and “**MaxUnavailable** '' settings during rolling updates in kubernetes, which helps in gradually scaling up your deployment.

Refer to this [link](https://codefresh.io/learn/software-deployment/kubernetes-rolloing-deployment-a-practical-guide/) for more information.